# T-SQL Randomize order of results using RAND(seed)

Tags: sql, t-sql, random, sql-server-2012

Im using the following statement (this is a shortened version as an example) to get results from my Microsoft SQL Express 2012 database:

```
SELECT id, name, city 
FROM tblContact 
ORDER BY RAND(xxx)
```

and injecting a seed stored in the session for the `xxx` part so that the results are consistently random for a given session (so when paging through results, the user doesn't see duplicates)

**PROBLEM: No matter what the seed is, the results get returned in the same order**

I have also tried this:

```
SELECT id, name, city, RAND(xxx) AS OrderValue 
FROM tblContact 
ORDER BY OrderValue
```

Both give the same (unexpected result) - am I using this incorrectly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value of `rand(seed)` will be the same for the entire query, You my want to use the ID column to generate random value on the row per row basis:

```
SELECT id, name, city, RAND(xxx + id) AS OrderValue 
  FROM tblContact ORDER BY OrderValue
```

However I've been developing some functionality in the past where I needed to have random order for different session, but the same order within the same session. At that time I have used `HASHBYTES()` and it worked very well:

```
 SELECT id, name, city, HASHBYTES('md5',cast(xxx+id as varchar)) AS OrderValue 
   FROM tblContact ORDER BY OrderValue
```

Comment: I CANNOT get `RAND(xxx + id) AS OrderValue` to order the list randomly - my query is returning `0` for all rows. However, the second option using HASHBYTES works like a charm ;) Thank you for that.

Comment: Yes I know that the `RAND(xxx + id)` has limitation and I also had a trouble  when I was developing aforementioned functionality, therefore I mentioned the `HASHBYTES` as it works much better.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, Rand() is calculated once for the query. To get a random order, use ORDER BY NEWID().

Answer (score 1):

Often, the `newid()` function is used for this purpose:

```
SELECT id, name, city
FROM tblContact
ORDER BY newid();
```

I have heard that `rand(checksum(newid()))` actually has better properties as a random number generator:

```
SELECT id, name, city
FROM tblContact
ORDER BY rand(checksum(newid()));
```

If you want consistent result from one query to the next, then @dimt's solution using `id` or a function of `id`.